# Best approach to make a localized website

Tags: localization

What's the best way to make a website localized to multi languages?

I'm working on a website, and our manager wants it to be like:

http://www.website.com - default to english
http://fr.website.com - french
http://de.website.com - german

He says it's good for SEO, some developers wants to make it based on cookie and user's accept-language, so the url would always be http://website.com but content would be based on cookie/accept-language.

What you think?

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This article appears to have a good guide to your question: http://www.antezeta.com/blog/domains-seo/

Essentially, they recommend localizing by TLD most, followed by Subdomain, followed by directories

Cookies are a bad idea because Google will not be able to index your localized content.

Comment: That link is not useful now

Answer (score 2):

This might be late answer but I will give you anyway (my hope is it will benefit others).

### Should http://www.example.com/ default to English?

No. You should always **detect** User's preferred language. That is, web browser will give you AcceptLanguage header with languages that end user is able to understand. If it happens that the most preferred one is not the one that your web site/web application supports, you should try to fall back to next language from AcceptLanguage. Only when nothing fits, you should fall back to your default language (usually English, United States).

### Should we used languages as part of domain?

It seems a good idea. When you detected the language, you might want to redirect user to appropriate page. It could be something like http://french.example.com/, http://german.example.com/ or http://www.example.com/index.html?lang=fr.
It is good to have such mechanism implemented - in this case one could actually bookmark correct language. Of course, if somebody navigates to your web site with language as a parameter, you will ***skip detection*** as it is pointless at this time.

### To sum up:

You may should detect language that web browser serves you and appear as you have multiple web sites (one language each). That is how user might choose which one to bookmark. And of course web search engines will probably index the contents separately, but they would rather look for robots.txt, so... Either way it is good to appear as several language-specific web sites.

Answer (score 0):

I once heard a teacher of mine say that when he does this, he simple makes php files called "eng.php" "fr.php" and so on...

In these files are associative arrays. The key's are always the same but the translation is different.

Then you need only require the correct language file at the top of you PHP files and if you parse the keys, it'll always be in the correct language.

Comment: Eh, that'll get pretty hard to maintain pretty quickly IMO

Comment: @AustinBurk That's actually how a lot of translation services do their work

Answer (score 0):

Most open-sourced approaches to localization and globalization involve a lot of developer overhead and complexity in maintenance as copy and code become more complex.

My current company Localize.js solves this complex pain point seamlessly, by tracking website phrase changes, automated ordering of translations, as well as dynamic rendering of languages for you.

https://localizejs.com/

Feel free to email me @ johnny@localizejs.com, if you have any questions